# Jasmine - How do I mock a finally call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a test that creates a controller like such...

```
  this.createScope = function(scope) {
    if (scope) {
      this.scope = scope;
    } else {
      this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }
    this.controller = $controller("menuController", {
      "$scope": this.scope,
      updateActionList: function() {
        return {
          finally: function() {}
        };
      }
    });
  };
```

I added this part...

```
      updateActionList: function() {
        return {
          finally: function() {}
        };
      }
```

Because when I run my tests, all of them fail because....

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'updateActionList().finally')
```

updateActionList() is a local function that is called in the actual code like this...

```
updateActionList().finally(function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

updateActionList() returns a promise from getThings() with a .then and a .finally blocks.

I just want the finally block to resolve itself really so the tests can pass.

Or is there some other thing I need to do? I'm not sure why the finally is undefined.

Comment: It'd help for an answer if you showed an example of how one of your tests attempt to use `updateActionList()`.

Comment: @miqid It's a local function in the file, they don't directly call it just call the file that's being tested.

Comment: @Carson, is `updateActionList` function injected? is it on scope of the controller? elaborate how it is a "local function" and how it gets called and all.. need those details..

Comment: @tanmay sorry. It's not injected, it's not attached to scope. It's inside the controller function, declared in there, and then called within that function with the .finally attached after it. When I run the code, the functionality works as expected. When I test, it complains with the error I provided. Which leads me to think something with Jasmine isn't properly being mocked. I can't really post the entire code itself, but does that clarify?

Comment: Ah I realized the piece of the puzzle I was missing, I was misunderstanding where the promise that `updateActionList` returned came from and needed to update the `finally` block of the mock to also have a `finally`. I updated the question with those details and gave an answer in case anyone else comes across this question with a similar case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this call...

```
updateActionList().finally(function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

returns a promise from some other function, essentially my problem was that the function returning the promise *before* updateActionList() mock needed another finally call.

```
  this.getThings = jasmine.createSpy("getThings").and.returnValue({
    then: function(cb) {
      cb(self.mockPlugins);
      return {
        finally: function(cb) {
          cb();
          return {
            finally: function(cb) {
              cb();
            }
          };
        }
      };
    }
  });
```